# sending images using python tcp socket

Tags: python-2.7, tcp, network-programming, python-sockets

i'm new in python and english :). i'm trying to send an image file usşng python sockets and i have written this cosdes. it says it work but i get an empty file or missing image file.
this is the codes i've written:

**server:**

```
import socket


host = socket.gethostname()

port = 5000

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.bind((host, port))

s.listen(1)

sunucu , adres = s.accept()

print "baglanti saglandi"

def recvall(baglanti, buf):

    data = ""
    while len(data) < buf:

        packet = baglanti.recv(buf - len(data))

        if not packet:

            return None

        data += packet

    return data


f = open("ggg.png", "w")

while True:

    veri = sunucu.recv(512)

    if not veri:

        break

    f.write(veri)

f.close()

print "resim alindi."


sunucu.close()

s.close()
```

**and client:**

```
import socket


host = socket.gethostname()

port = 5000

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect((host , port))



f = open("ornekresim.png", "r")

while True:

    veri = f.readline(512)

    if not veri:

        break

    s.send(veri)

f.close()

print "resim gonderildi"

s.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

By default the Python function [`open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) opens file in *text* mode, meaning it will handle all input/output as *text*, while an image is decidedly *binary*.

A file in text mode will do thing like translating newline sequences (which are different on different systems). That means the data you read will be corrupted.

To open a file in binary mode, then append `'b'` to the mode flags, like e.g.

```
f = open("ornekresim.png", "rb")  # <-- Note the 'b' in the mode
```

---

However, with your code this leads to another problem, namely that you can't use `readline` anymore. Not that it made much sense anyway, reading binary data as lines since there are no "lines" in binary data.

You have to use the [`read`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.read) function instead.